# What could be wrong with the Vue 3 compat build setup?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

TLDR: custom events (`$listeners`) won't be automatically binded in the vue 3 compat build. It is as if all the components would have `inheritAttrs: false` (although `$attrs` will be binded and it doesn't include `class`/`style` either as the docs say it would)

I followed the official vue 3 migration guide with the compat build, it should've been relatively easy to migrate, however it seems a bit harder as expected. So I added the following code to the `vue.config.js`:

```js
        // Vue 2 => Vue 3 migration config
        config.resolve.alias.set('vue', '@vue/compat');

        config.module
            .rule('vue')
            .use('vue-loader')
            .tap((options) => ({
                ...options,
                compilerOptions: {
                    compatConfig: {
                        MODE: 3,
                    },
                },
            }));
```

Most of the work is already done, however I realised that none of the listeners seems to be working. After some investigation I found out that the `$listeners` object won't be automatically binded as they should be. They aren't included for some reason in the `$attrs` object neither will they be inherited (I guess they are related).

I tried `INSTANCE_LISTENERS: false,` option with both `false` and `true` values, unfortunately neither seemed to work. Now the only option I can see right now is adding `v-on="$listeners"` to all components that may need to bind any events. This is obviously not a good solution, it is hacky and they are also removed in vue 3 completely but I couldn't think of another solution. Did anybody else experience the same and know maybe a better solution for this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

EDIT:

I thought maybe sharing the dependencies could help in detecting the issue so here they are:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.5",
    "@datadog/browser-logs": "^2.17.0",
    "@datadog/browser-rum": "^2.17.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.1",
    "@rd-internal/rd-vue-gtm": "^1.1.0",
    "@vue/apollo-option": "^4.0.0-alpha.15",
    "@vue/compat": "^3.2.23",
    "@vue/runtime-dom": "^3.2.23",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "apollo-link-schema": "^1.2.5",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^14.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.17.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
    "graphql": "^15.7.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.7",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.12.0",
    "loader-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.merge": "^4.6.2",
    "lodash.set": "^4.3.2",
    "lodash.some": "^4.6.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.1",
    "tinycolor2": "^1.4.2",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.1.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.23",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.0.7",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-ctk-date-time-picker": "^2.5.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.0-beta.22",
    "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
    "vuelidate-error-extractor": "^2.4.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/eslint-plugin-vue-i18n": "^1.2.0",
    "@jagi/jest-transform-graphql": "^1.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.30.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.23",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.3.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.1.0",
    "casual-browserify": "^1.5.19-2",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^35.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue-scoped-css": "^1.3.0",
    "full-icu": "^1.3.4",
    "glob": "^7.1.7",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "hygen": "^6.1.0",
    "inflection": "^1.13.1",
    "jest-junit": "^12.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.5.2",
    "style-resources-loader": "^1.4.1",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0",
    "stylelint-declaration-use-variable": "^1.7.3",
    "stylelint-no-unsupported-browser-features": "^5.0.1",
    "stylelint-order": "^4.1.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.20.1",
    "ts-jest": "^24.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~4.0.0",
    "vue-composition-test-utils": "^1.0.3"
  },
```

Comment: Can you share a reproduction of the problem, where the listeners are not found in `$attrs`?

Comment: Hi @tony19, I tried making a reproduction on codesandbox but I couldn't reproduce it with a simple small repo. Not sure which dependency may cause this issue so I shared the dependencies of the project, pehaprs it helps

Comment: Couldn't find a solution for this, so after 1-2 days spent on research decided to just start using vue 3 without the compat build and do a "big" migration instead